# Nginx wildcard subdomain and domain server block showing same project

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup a saas project. So I have two projects. Main landing page built with nextjs will run in lets say `example.com` and another react nextjs project will run all wildcard subdomains.

These are the steps I took.

1. In my namecheap domain, I used A record with @ to my IP
2. I created another record with * and pointing to the same IP

Here is my server block

```
server {


    server_name example.com;

     location / {
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
       # proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding    "";
        proxy_set_header  Proxy              "";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

     location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3333/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding    "";
        proxy_set_header  Proxy              "";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    

    
    
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

Now the issue is, this block is executing for all subdomains and main domain. I also tried setting up a new block with  `server_name *.example.com;` but this never executes. Always this `server_name example.com;` serve the same one project.

How can I run two projects?

Thank you.

Comment: I would try using two server blocks.

Comment: I created two server block and last one with `server_name *.example.com;` which never runs

Comment: Well, that should work [according to the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that both `server` blocks are present with the correct `server_name` and `listen` directives. **Always** reset the browser's cache between changes to the Nginx configuration.

Comment: Ok I think it's working now. I found that `listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot` this line was creating issue and server was not restarting. So when I commented this line and used only `listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot` then it worked